# Need help on how to retrieve the data from database and write it to a html file using java?

Tags: java, mysql, html

I have a mysql database with a table of 5 columns.

Now I need to get those data from that database table and view it in a html file (with table headers and table contents) using java.

Please help me with some tutorial links.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the steps:

1. Install mySql and create database for your app.
2. Get mySql connector jar.
3. Do a little bit coding to get connected with mySql db in your JSP page or in servlet.
4. Query in db and retrieve appropriate data.
5. Display that data in JSP.

[MySql database in JSP](http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysqldatabase.shtml): this tutorial might help you.

Comment: He can't upvote anything yet (rep too low). And I guess it's ok if he doesn't accept an answer right away...

Comment: @Sean: oh.. I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial point here is that you need to talk to the database.  You will use JDBC for this, along with a MySQL driver.

The official MySQL documentation for working with Java is at http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/ and there are a few tutorials.

If you are unfamiliar with JDBC, the official Java tutorial has a section on JDBC at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

If you just need to write a file containing HTML this is not hard if you know the appropriate tags.  If you need to do this in a servlet container, more details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code that builds a HTML table from a JDBC query. Use it as a starting point:

```
// insert your JDBC URL here
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:your-db-url");
// Edit this SQL Query so it makes sense
ResultSet resultSet = connection
                        .createStatement()
                        .executeQuery("select * from yourtable");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("<table>\n");
int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
sb.append("<tr>\n");
for(int n = 1; n <= columnCount; n++){
    sb.append("\t<th>")
      .append(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(n))
      .append("</th>\n");
}
sb.append("</tr>\n");
while(resultSet.next()){
    sb.append("<tr>\n");
    for(int n = 1; n <= columnCount; n++){
        sb.append("\t<td>")
          .append(resultSet.getString(n))
          .append("</td>\n");
    }
    sb.append("</tr>\n");

}
sb.append("</table>")
String table = sb.toString();
```

Comment: You need to escape data loaded from the database.

Comment: @Thorbjorn What does it mean?

Comment: @Anu it means that your db might contain all kinds of text or markup that looks strange in HTML.